# What do Java annotation ElementType constants mean?

Tags: java, annotations

[`java.lang.annotation.ElementType`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html):

A program element type. The constants of this enumerated type provide a simple classification of the declared elements in a Java program. These constants are used with the [`Target`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html) meta-annotation type **to specify where it is legal to use an annotation type**.

There are the following constants:

- **ANNOTATION_TYPE** - Annotation type declaration
- **CONSTRUCTOR** - Constructor declaration
- **FIELD** - Field declaration (includes enum constants)
- **LOCAL_VARIABLE** - Local variable declaration
- **METHOD** - Method declaration
- **PACKAGE** - Package declaration
- **PARAMETER** - Parameter declaration
- **TYPE** - Class, interface (including annotation type), or enum declaration

Can someone explain what each of them are (where they'd be annotated in actual code)?

Comment: Aren't the descriptions clear enough? Surely you understand at least some of them?

Comment: `@meriton:` I've only seen annotations on fields, methods, and classes, which probably corresponds with __FIELD__, __METHOD__, and __TYPE__. I'll post examples of annotations for each of these, and perhaps someone will fill out the rest?

Comment: Java 8 adds two new constants, TYPE_PARAMETER and TYPE_USE.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This summarizes the main ones:

```
@CustomTypeAnnotation
public class MyAnnotatedClass {
  @CustomFieldAnnotation
  private String foo;

  @CustomConstructorAnnotation
  public MyAnnotatedClass() {
  }

  @CustomMethodAnnotation
  public String bar(@CustomParameterAnnotation String str) {
    @CustomLocalVariableAnnotation String asdf = "asdf";
    return asdf + str;
  }
}
```

ANNOTATION_TYPE is an annotation on another annotation, like this:

```
@CustomAnnotationTypeAnnotation
public @interface SomeAnnotation {
  ..
}
```

Package is defined in a `package-info.java` file in the package, like this:

```
@CustomPackageLevelAnnotation
package com.some.package;

import com.some.package.annotation.PackageLevelAnnotation;
```

For more info on PACKAGE annotations see [here](http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/02/28/package-annotations/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405336/how-do-i-add-package-level-annotations-or-edit-package-info-java).

Comment: Answer would be that much better if you also included snippets for ANNOTATION_TYPE and for PACKAGE.

Comment: @JohnGlassmyer - A few years late, but I added more snippets for ANNOTATION_TYPE and PACKAGE. :-)

Answer (score 127):

Let's say the annotation to which you specify the `ElementType` is called `YourAnnotation`:

- ANNOTATION_TYPE - Annotation type declaration. **Note:** This goes on other annotations

  ```
  @YourAnnotation
  public @interface AnotherAnnotation {..}
  ```
- CONSTRUCTOR - Constructor declaration

  ```
  public class SomeClass {
      @YourAnnotation
      public SomeClass() {..}
  }
  ```
- FIELD - Field declaration (includes enum constants)

  ```
  @YourAnnotation
  private String someField;
  ```
- LOCAL_VARIABLE - Local variable declaration. **Note:** This can't be read at runtime, so it is used only for compile-time things, like the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation.

  ```
  public void someMethod() {
      @YourAnnotation int a = 0;
  }
  ```
- METHOD - Method declaration

  ```
  @YourAnnotation
  public void someMethod() {..}
  ```
- PACKAGE - Package declaration. **Note:** This can be used only in `package-info.java`.

  ```
  @YourAnnotation
  package org.yourcompany.somepackage;
  ```
- PARAMETER - Parameter declaration

  ```
  public void someMethod(@YourAnnotation param) {..}
  ```
- TYPE - Class, interface (including annotation type), or enum declaration

  ```
  @YourAnnotation
  public class SomeClass {..}
  ```

You can specify multiple `ElementType`s for a given annotation. E.g.:

```
@Target({ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.METHOD})
```

Comment: `@Bozho:` Thanks for the pro tip. I check-marked the thing below the vote counter.

Answer (score 4):

**TYPE**:

Annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})    // This annotation can only be applied to
public @interface Tweezable {  // class, interface, or enum declarations.
}
```

and an example usage:

```
@Tweezable
public class Hair {
    ...
}
```

Comment: OK, but what value does this add to your program?  What does it indicate to the interpreter, what does it do, etc?  What is the interpreter going to do with the information that this class is "@Tweezable"?  Java already has an interface keyword, you can simply write "public interface Tweezable".  What, if anything, does the annotation do, and does it duplicate the functionality of just declaring an interface the straightforward way?  This is the kind of question I came here hoping to find the answers to.