# How do I add package level annotations or edit package-info.java?

Tags: java, annotations, package, javadoc

I'm trying to add package level annotations but I don't have a clue on how to do it. Examples are appreciated.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Summary from the article [here](http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/02/28/package-annotations/)

In package-info.java:

```
@PackageLevelAnnotation
package blammy; // package with a package level annotation.


import blammy.annotation.PackageLevelAnnotation;
```

In PackageLevelAnnotation.java

```
package blammy.annotation;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.PACKAGE)
public @interface PackageLevelAnnotation
{
  // stuff as required.
}
```

Edit: more package level info.
Here is a link to the package chapter in the Java Language Spec: [packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html)

Comment: Where is package-info.java? Is it provided or somewhere or do I have to create it? Where would I need to create this file if so. Thanks.

Comment: In my example above, the file package-info.java should be in the blammy package (i.e. the blammy source directory).

Comment: yes, one per package.  see edits in the answer for another info link

Comment: @DwB - I have a related question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/34980398/1735836
What to put in place of `// stuff as required.` ?  I need an explanation for Dummies.

Comment: For copy and pasters, change `@Retention` to `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME` if you want visibility outside of compilation.

Answer (score 41):

**In eclipse**

Since package-info.java isn't a valid identifier for a class it cannot be created as a class in Eclipse.

I found that when you create a new package there is a check box to check if you want a package-info.java.

To create a package-info.java file in an existing package:

1. Right-click on the package where you want a package-info.java.
2. Select New->Package.
3. Check the Create package-info.java check box.
4. Click on Finish.

Comment: This does not work in my Eclipse version (3.7.2) - which version is required for this solution?

Comment: I have Juno, version 4.2.0.

Comment: To add such a file to an existing package, I right-click on the package in the Project Explorer → New → Other → File and manually name it package-info.java. I keep forgetting exactly what to call the file and which annotations to add, though, so I'd love to read of a more elegant way.

Answer (score 5):

## `package-info.java`

The `package-info.java` is a Java file that can be added to any Java source package. Its purpose is to provide a home for package level documentation and package level annotations.

Simply create the `package-info.java` file. Add the package declaration in the file.  In fact, the only thing the package-info.java file must contain is the package declaration.

Example of a minimal package info file:

```java
package com.example.myapp.backend.data;
```

Example of a package-level annotation, [`@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/parametersarenonnullbydefault-annotation.html):

```java
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
package com.example.myapp.backend.data;

import javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault;
```

For more info, see the [Java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), in [*The Java® Language Specification*, section 7.4.1 *Named Packages*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.1).

Answer (score 3):

Open explorer, go to src/your package folder.
right click -> Create new textfile:  name it package-info.java.

Go back to eclipse and edit and add the desired content.