# Is there anything like Lombok @AllArgConstructor for @MockBeans?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, lombok

I use [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) for my Java projects.

My Controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private RegisterService registerService;
    private UserService userService;
    private UserValidator userValidator;
    private LoginService loginService;
    /*
     * rest of the controller
     */
}
```

so the controller must look like this:

```
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @MockBean
    private RegisterService registerService;

    @MockBean 
    private UserService userService;

    @MockBean
    private LoginService loginService;
    
    @MockBean
    private UserValidator UserValidator;

    /*
     * rest of the contoller test
     */
}
```

Just to make programming less code-monkey, is there anything like @AllMockArgConstructor?
Or any way, I don't always have to add all services?

If this is a stupid question, please explain me why.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it cannot be done,

[`@MockBeans`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) annotation target is applied only to fields and types, and not for methods, you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550292/what-do-java-annotation-elementtype-constants-mean).

---

If `@MockBeans` was able to support also methods then it was can be done that way:

```
@Getter(onMethod_={@MockBean} )
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Spring `@MockBean` is more or less only a wrapper over Mocktio `@Mock`...
can it be done with `@Mock`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I accepted your answer, even it was not the one I wanted to read :-(  
I will read the information you gave me.