# Can I assign a value to a variable in class by @parameters annotation?

Tags: selenium, annotations, testng

This is the code I used to have to open its corresponding web driver by `browser`.

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters("browser")
public void openDriver(String browser) throws Exception {
    driver = help.getRemoteDriver(help.GRID,browser);
.....
```

Just wondering is there any way to assign value to a variable in class? not in method? for example.

```
public class Test{
   WebDriver driver;

   @Parameters("browser")
   public String browser = //"{browser}"; 

   @Test
   void test1(){
      driver = help.getRemoteDriver(help.GRID,browser);
   }

}
```

So I can call this String `browser` variable without `@Parameters` in the next new test. Even its child class.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You exactly did that in the first code snippet by getting `browser` in a `beforeClass` method. Only difference is that along with initializing `driver`, you can declare a `browser` field in the class and initialize it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Parameters` annotation `METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR, TYPE` target ElementTypes defined.

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR, TYPE})
public @interface Parameters {|
...
```

There is no `FIELD` in target, so *it's not possible to set this annotation for the class field*.

But you might also set it in constructor.

```
public class MyTest {

   WebDriver driver;

   public String browser;

   @Parameters({ "browser" })
   public MyTest(String browser) {
       this.browser = browser;
   }

   @Test
   void test1(){
      driver = help.getRemoteDriver(help.GRID,browser);
   }

}
```

*testng.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suite-name">
    <test name="test-name">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="my.package.name.MyTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

---

[What do Java annotation ElementType constants mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550292/what-do-java-annotation-elementtype-constants-mean)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Probably I have to set a filed variable by the constructor and it would be more suitable.

Comment: Excuse me... How can I declare the MyTest then? to construct MyTest, I should pass the String..

Comment: @deokyongsong as you see, you might define a parameter in testng.xml, so it will be passed to the constructor. `@Parameters` annotation aimed to inject parameters from xml, that's its the main goal by design.